# Openstack installation fails

Tags: openstack

I'm trying to install OpenStack using the Ubunutu 15.04 release.
I have installed the server edition on a HP ProLiant server with 4 CPU's, 2TB raid disks, 20GB of memory and assumed this would be an easy install.

I have been trying to get the MAAS stuff to work for two days, but I could never get any nodes to register. I think this is due to my other machines does not have Wake-on-LAN support, but this is probably another issue.

So, I went on to only install OpenStack on this server.
The package install went well, but when running the installation script, it fails with the following error:

```
root@linux1:~# openstack-install 
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/logging/__init__.py", line 980, in emit
    stream.write(msg)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u2022' in position 7: ordinal not in range(128)
Call stack:
  File "/usr/bin/openstack-install", line 253, in <module>
    install.start()
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/install.py", line 152, in start
    'Create a new Openstack Password', self._save_password)
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/gui.py", line 673, in show_password_input
    widget = PasswordInput(title, cb)
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/ui/__init__.py", line 232, in __init__
    self.show()
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/ui/dialog.py", line 49, in show
    w = self._build_widget()
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/ui/dialog.py", line 93, in _build_widget
    self.input_lbox))
Message: 'Num items: 2, items: <ListBox selectable box widget>'
Arguments: ()
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/logging/__init__.py", line 980, in emit
    stream.write(msg)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u2022' in position 7: ordinal not in range(128)
Call stack:
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/utils.py", line 63, in global_exchandler
    log.debug("".join(tb_list))
Message: 'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/usr/bin/openstack-install", line 253, in <module>\n    install.start()\n  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/install.py", line 154, in start\n    self.loop.run()\n  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/ev.py", line 116, in run\n    self.loop.run()\n  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/main_loop.py", line 274, in run\n    self.screen.run_wrapper(self._run)\n  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/raw_display.py", line 268, in run_wrapper\n    return fn()\n  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/main_loop.py", line 314, in _run\n    self.draw_screen()\n  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/main_loop.py", line 566, in draw_screen\n    self.screen.draw_screen(self.screen_size, canvas)\n  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/raw_display.py", line 770, in draw_screen\n    self._term_output_file.write(l)\nUnicodeEncodeError: \'ascii\' codec can\'t encode character \'\\u250c\' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)\n'
Arguments: ()
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/logging/__init__.py", line 980, in emit
    stream.write(msg)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u2022' in position 7: ordinal not in range(128)
Call stack:
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/utils.py", line 91, in cleanup
    log.info("Cleanup, saving latest config object.")
Message: 'Cleanup, saving latest config object.'
Arguments: ()
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/logging/__init__.py", line 980, in emit
    stream.write(msg)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u2022' in position 7: ordinal not in range(128)
Call stack:
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/utils.py", line 97, in cleanup
    log.debug('Attempting to reset the terminal')
Message: 'Attempting to reset the terminal'
Arguments: ()
</code>

I thought this problem was cased by a bad locale, but I don't think this is the case:
<code>
root@linux1:~# locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
LC_CTYPE="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_PAPER="C"
LC_NAME="C"
LC_ADDRESS="C"
LC_TELEPHONE="C"
LC_MEASUREMENT="C"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="C"
LC_ALL=C
```

I have tried to understand what the problem is but I can't find any reason.
This is a fresh install so I assume it would work without problems.

Anyone?

Comment: This still looks like a locale problem, do you mind opening an issue at https://github.com/Ubuntu-Solutions-Engineering/openstack-installer/issues so we can look into this further?

Comment: also for reference this is my locale setting on 15.04: http://paste.ubuntu.com/11212264/

Answer (score 1):

You have more locale environment variables set than you really need.
`LANG` is a fallback for when no `LC*` variable is set, and `LC_ALL` overrides all the others.

So in your case, `LC_ALL=C` is overriding `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` and all the others. The installer needs UTF-8. I'm not actually sure which specific `LC_*` variable(s) it uses, probably several of them.

You *should* be able to fix this by only setting `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` and making sure that all the others are unset, or by setting `LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8` and the others won't matter. If you can un-set them, that'd help future confusion, but it should work either way.

For more information than you probably want about all this, see the "Internationalisation Variables" section of the UNIX spec's [Environment Variables Chapter](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xbd/envvar.html), and the man page [locale(7)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man7/locale.7.html).

Comment: Thanks, but this is the default for the ubunutu installation. If this was the case, the installation guide would state "you need to unset the locale variables", but it doesn't. I'll have another try. Thanks!